# What for do I need the permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS?

Tags: android, android-permissions

[Android dev. documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) says

> MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
>   Allows an application to modify global audio settings.
>   Protection level: normal

It's not clear to me why someone may need this permission in their `AndroidManifest`. I know, that you can initialize `MediaPlayer` and play audio without this permission.

Can you please explain this permission in more details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends upon what you want to do. Of course you can play audio with [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) but purpose of [`MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) is to modify audio using [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/AudioManager).

For example: [AudioManager#startBluetoothSco()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/AudioManager#startBluetoothSco%28%29) requires `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

It's mainly used when an user wants to change sound redirection to a different output/sink device (like a Bluetooth SCO). Some Android implementation could require this Permission even when trying to change phone Ring to Vibrate (or viceversa) mode.

Comment: do u have an example?

Comment: Yes, it is used when for example you are playing an audio and want to change to earphones when proximity sensor is triggered and vice versa.